# ';' expected.Vetur(1005) showing on computed function in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to vue3 and try to build some sideprojects, but it will show **';' expected.Vetur(1005)** when I try to use the computed function. but sometimes it's also fine to use the same syntax like the following file, and after some research, I already tried turning down vetur experiemental option and reopen the vscode, but it didn't work.

```
“vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService”: false
```

[image]

```js
<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import marked from "marked";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
    };
  },
  computed(){
    // (){ will have missed ";" error 
    markedText(){
      return marked(this.text);
    }
  }
  
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computed` is property not function so try with `computed:` instead `computed()`